# Extract greatest index from an array using python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

I am new to python and want to extract greatest count from an array,

Using counter,
x = Counter(matchedAr)
print x

I have the following list.
Counter({6: 452, 5: 439, 2: 391, 9: 379, 7: 361, 4: 324, 0: 313, 3: 310, 8: 274, 1: 248})

How can I extract the greatest count i.e., 6 from this list?

Comment: That is neither an array nor a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Counter.most_common()

```
>>> s
Counter({6: 452, 5: 439, 2: 391, 9: 379, 7: 361, 4: 324, 0: 313, 3: 310, 8: 274, 1: 248})
>>> s.most_common()[0][0]
6
>>>
```

OR:

```
Counter(list).most_commmon(1)

>>> s = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5]
>>> Counter(s).most_common(1)
[(1, 4)]
>>>
```

Here is the help:

```
most_common(self, n=None) method of collections.Counter instance
    List the n most common elements and their counts from the most
    common to the least.  If n is None, then list all element counts.

    >>> Counter('abcdeabcdabcaba').most_common(3)
    [('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('c', 3)]
>>>
```

Comment: please don't forget to select as an answer :)